# Need to find in all system files that are less than 7 days old, starts with "L" and are .txt, then generate an output file based on that

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, find

I’m working with Ubuntu and need to find in all system files that are less than 7 days old, starts with `L` and are `.txt`, then generate an output file based on that.

This is what I have so far:

```
nohup find / -type f -ctime -7 -name \*.txt \*L | tee /tmp/log``-`hostname`-`date -I`.log
```

But somehow the output is

```
find: paths must precede expression: `*L'
```

I tried a lot of ways to put the `L` in the script. What can be done to get this to work?

---

<sup>This is a repost of a [deleted question from another user](https://superuser.com/q/1590418/167207). I was in the middle of posting an answer when they suddenly deleted the question, thus I am reposting here so I can share my solution with others.</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on Ubuntu 16.04; should work on other versions as well since it is using GNU `find`:

```
find / -type f -ctime -7 -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*\/L.[a-zA-Z]+.(txt)$"  -print 2>/dev/null |\
  while read filepath
  do
    echo "${filepath}" >> log-$(hostname)-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").log
  done
```

Note the `-regextype posix-extended` and the `-iregex` with the regex pattern following it.

And — for others who might stumble across this — this variant of that script works well for macOS Catalina (10.5.7) which uses BSD `find`:

```
find -E / -type f -ctime -7 -regex ".*\/L.[a-zA-Z]+.(txt)$"  -print 2>/dev/null |\
  while read filepath
  do
    echo "${filepath}" >> log-$(hostname)-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").log
  done
```

Note the `-E` (interpret regex patterns) and the `-iregex` (case insensitive) regex patters.

I prefer this regex-bass method because I can change the regex pattern to have multiple file extensions like this to find files with `.txt`, `.jpeg` and `png` extentions:

```
 ".*\.(txt|jpeg|png)$"
```